HP Laptop keeps trying to open 'hpdiags' link on startup
I have an HP laptop with Windows 11, which I cleaned up to uninstall all the HP bloatware: Support assistant, Connection optimizer, etc. However, the bloatware didn't uninstall correctly, after every restart I get a window saying "Get an app to open this 'hpdiags' link":

Browsing the store doesn't reveal the missing app.
How can I find out which program is the origin of this window so I can uninstall it? If that's not possible, how can I find the program that is compatible with 'hpdiags' links, so that I (hopefully) get a notification instead of the error message?

I'd search the registry for the phrase hpdiags and start from there

Could also be items in task scheduler

@JaromandaX I wiped everything related to hpdiags from the registry, and it seems to have helped. I'll wait a couple more days to be sure.
